# Django collectstatic --no input Yes instead of no

Tags: python, django, makefile

I am using Django3 and i have currently the following command in my makefile for "Build"

```
python3 manage.py collectstatic
```

to automate my buildprocess with a pipeline i would like to get rid of the prompt that asks

> You have requested to collect static files at the destination location
> as specified in your settings:
>
> URL
>
> This will overwrite existing files! Are you sure you want to do this?
>
> Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel

i found that out that i can add "--no-input" for the collectstatic at the end, but this will answer "no" in this case.
Is there a way how i could say the script to answer "Yes" by default instead?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As mentioned in Django docs:

**On subsequent collectstatic runs (if STATIC_ROOT isn’t empty), files are copied only if they have a modified timestamp greater than the timestamp of the file in STATIC_ROOT.**

So django by default overwrites your modified files on collectstatic command, --noinput flag means it will not ask for your permission.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. What if the timestamp is less than the timestamp of the file in STATIC_ROOT but you wish to force a yes response with no-input?